# how to write unit testing for modal or alert popup in ionic 4

Tags: unit-testing, angular7, ionic4

I want to cover unit testing for alert controller popup and callback handler in ionic 4?

```js
it('should open popup', () => {
  component.showAlertPopup();
  const popupElem = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('alert-inner-button'));
  console.log('popup element', popupElem);
});
```

```js
async showAlertPopup() {
  const alertOpts: AlertOptions = {
    message: 'applied successfully',
    button: [{
      text: 'YES',
      handler: () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('app/home');
      }
    }]
  };
  const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create(alertOpts);
  console.log('alert', alert);
  alert.present();
}
```

I expected the popup element but it is undefined.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am also facing the same problem

Comment: @PersianBlue not yet... only way is to mock the entire ionic alert and modal components! Thats how i did in my project.